# How to implement static batching like in unity in DirectX 11

Tags: 3d, directx, sharpdx

As a unity user, i'm confused about how i could implement something similar to their static batching.
Multiple meshes (diferent meshes but same material) display as being rendered in 1 draw call, however i'm not finding how i could do that in DirectX.

I can see how to draw in DirectX using Draw(). I know you can draw the same meshes multiple times in a single call (DrawiInstanced()?) however i don't get how you can draw multiple different meshes in a single draw call. I would love to be pointed into the right direction or given a sample showing say a cube & a triangle being rendered in a single draw call sharing a single material.

I'm using DirectX11.1 & doing so through SharpDX, a SharpDX example is prefered but a DX one is fine, however no DX9/10 examples if the correct way to do this changed, i'm strictly only interested in DX11.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mechanism to do this automatically, but if you have multiple meshes that share input layout and "material" (shaders, textures, etc.), you can simply concatenate the vertex and index buffers (with indices patched to the base vertex offset as necessary).

As an example that draws a cube and triangle, just set up your VB to contain both:

```
float cubeAndTriangleVertices[] = 
{
  -1, -1, -1, // cube vertices
  -1, -1,  1,
  -1,  1, -1,
  -1,  1,  1,
   1, -1, -1,
   1, -1,  1,
   1,  1, -1,
   1,  1,  1,
   2,  0,  0, // triangle vertices
   2,  1,  0,
   3,  0,  0,
};
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA cubeAndTriangleVData = { cubeAndTriangleVertices };
device->CreateVertexBuffer(&cubeAndTriangleVData, &vb);

unsigned short cubeAndTriangleIndices[] =
{
  0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, // -x face
  7, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, // +x face
  0, 1, 4, 4, 1, 5, // -y face
  2, 6, 3, 6, 7, 3, // +y face
  6, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, // -z face
  3, 7, 1, 7, 5, 1, // +z face
  8, 9, 10, // triangle
}

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA cubeAndTriangleIData = { cubeAndTriangleIndices };
device->CreateIndexBuffer(&cubeAndTriangleIData, &ib);

// ...pipeline setup

context->DrawIndexed(6 * 6 + 3, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I was wondering how this worked since i didn't see how you could submit multiple meshes even if they were in the same buffer in a draw call. Am i understanding correctly that it works because you're drawing using DrawIndexed and thus can specify faces? I've only been using draw so far (so polys are drawn in the order in which they are in the buffer) hence why i didn't see how this was feasible. Am i correct in assuming there is no way to do the same without specifying faces? No magic Draw(Model1Index,Model2Index,Model3Index) or similar?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau You should be able to combine meshes into the same vertex buffer even if you're using a non-indexed Draw call (though nearly all games today use DrawIndexed).  To convert the code in my answer to be non-indexed, you can simply create a new vertex buffer with (6 * 6 + 3) vertices, each with a value equal to vertices[indices[i]].  The key concept here is that D3D doesn't really care about "meshes" - if you have multiple meshes with the same shaders, textures, etc. then it can basically treat it as a single object.

Comment: Actually i see where i was confused now, if i submit V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 i'm going to get a V1 V2 V3 face & a V4 V5 V6 face, there will be no long between vertex 3 & 4 anyway in a triangle list, i was thinking of another layout (a tri per set of vertices so 1 2 3 / 2 3 4 / 3 4 5 etc). So i think i immagined a nonexistant problem.